# Triangle with div

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a block with a left triangle. I made this by applying one triangle to another triangle. But triangle border have got 2-3px instead 1px. How to fix it? Maybe you know other ways of implementing? Thank you very mutch........................................................................
....................................
....................................

```css
#crumbs ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 110px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;     
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
#crumbs ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

#crumbs ul li a:before {
    content: '';
    border-top: 56px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 56px solid transparent;
    border-right: 13px solid #e6e6e6;
    position: absolute;
    left: -13.7px;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#crumbs ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 55px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 55px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: -11.5px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#crumbs ul li a span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -6px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span></span>
                <img src="1.png" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#crumbs ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 110px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;     
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
#crumbs ul li{
        list-style:none;
}

#crumbs ul li a:before {
    content: "";
 border-top: 56px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 56px solid transparent;
 border-right: 13px solid #e6e6e6;
 position: absolute;
 left: -14px;
 top: -1px;
 z-index: 2;
}

#crumbs ul li a:after {    
content: "";
    border-top: 56px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 56px solid transparent;
    border-right: 13px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: -13px;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#crumbs ul li a span:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: -6px;
 width: 6px;
 height: 6px;
 margin-top: -4px;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 z-index: 99;
 }
```

```html
<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">
         <span></span>
         <img src="1.png" alt="">
        </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your pixel values were a little off. I cleaned them up a little and the border has a consistent width now.

Comment: No problem! By the way, try avoiding decimal pixel values, that's generally not good practice :)